# Secure Webservice (WCF) without storing credentials on consumer application

Tags: c#, security, authentication, web-services, authorization

I have a customer that sells a lottery analysis application. In this application, he consumes a webservice (my service, I mean, belongs to the company I work for now) to get statistical data about lottery results, bets made, amounts, etc., from all across the globe. The access to this webservice is paid, and each consult costs X credits.

Some people have disassembled this lottery application and found the api key/auth key used to access the paid webservice, and started to use it.

I would like to prevent this from happening again, but I can't find a way to authenticate on the webservice without storing the auth. keys on the application. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish such task?

ps1.Can't ask for the users to input any kind of credentials. Has to be transparent for them (they shouldn't know what is happening).

ps2. Can't use digital certificates for the same reason above, not to mention it's easy to retrieve them and we would fall into the original problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone suggested releasing a client for this service (in a dll for example) and sending along the request the hash of the application, maintaining server side an list of authorized applications.

I liked the idea, but seems to suffer from the same problem of embedding keys into the app code.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to prevent?  Are you trying to stop users from accessing the web service without the front-end application?  Is the only authentication you do on the server based on a key that's shared by all copies of the application?

Comment: Yes, locking the webservice to a single application (in that case, my customers front-end app) would be a great way to do this.

What I'm trying to do is prevent users from using my services with a key stolen from my customers application.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, you cannot do this efficiently. You face a similar problem as the video game company.

You might use some form of 'code obfuscation' but it's a form of security through obscurity and you cannot guaranty the effectiveness of this.

You might reduce the exposure by using different keys for each client and, on the server side, ensure a key cannot be used by different client simultaneously. This is basically what the the video game industry does that has a real benefit.

Comment: I cannot control who uses the application. I have a customer who uses my services in his application and distributes this app to his customers. So the problem is my customer's customers :(

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done.

You have to either embed the credentials into the application (hard coded or whatever) or prompt the user to enter them.

Locking the web services to a single application is also ineffective since it can be easily discovered and bypassed, just like embedding the credentials.

Since you cant control the clients or the environment(restrict access by IP, domain, etc.), IMHO you're pretty screwed :(